# how to get previous year in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to get previous years in SQLite where clause using sql clause. It did not work. Could somebody help me?

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
     select * from Spending where strftime('%Y',Spending_DT )<= strftime('%Y', date('now'))-3;
```

it is the number that causes the problem. It seems to me that substract 3 works in select clause such as:

```
    select  strftime('%Y', date('now'))-3;
    output=2013
```

but it did not work when the same phrase using in where clause

many many thanks

Jing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting both sides of your comparator like so:

**Example**

```
select * from test;
spending_Dt
-----------
2012-03-03
2013-03-03
2014-03-03
2015-03-03
2016-03-03
```

**Query**

```
select strftime('%Y', spending_dt) as years
from test 
where cast(strftime('%Y', spending_dt) as int) <= cast(strftime('%Y', date('now')) as int)-3;
```

**Result**

```
years
----------
2012
2013
```